# How to add Oracle Database Driver in a Java Play project?

Tags: java, oracle, sbt

I'm going to access a database using `OJDBC`. My project is a Java play project and using `SBT`. I added,

> "com.oracle" % "ojdbc14" % "10.2.0.4.0"

But when I'm compiling the project with this,
It says,

```
  :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: 
  [warn]::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
  [warn]:: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
  [warn]::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
  [warn]:: com.oracle#ojdbc14;10.2.0.4.0!ojdbc14.jar
  [warn]::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Also I tried to download the `jar` manually using [this](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/oracle/ojdbc14/10.2.0.4.0/ojdbc14-10.2.0.4.0.jar) link. Then I got `404`.
Is there a way to add the `OJDBC14` dependency to a Java play project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the maven users (like me) who are trying to download the jars from maven repo: Stop!

The jar's metadata is indexed and pom file is available on maven central but the actual jar is not available. Try clicking on the download link:

```
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle/classes12/10.2.0.2.0
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle/ojdbc14/10.2.0.4.0
```

So, you need to get the jar from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html

And then install to your local repo.

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc14 \
 -Dversion=10.2.0.4.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=ojdbc.jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

In SBT's config add

`resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal` to enable local maven repo

<sup><sub>P.S.: If you are still reading it: I wish oracle deployed them on maven, (with a note stating if you are using the jar means you are agreeing our terms)!</sub></sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can download `ojdbc.jar` in the following link

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html

Maven repo does not offer a `ojdbc jar` link, because oracle Unauthorized

Comment: Oracle JDBC driver is not present on Maven repository.  So, you will need to download it from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html.       
After downloading it, you will have to manually install it on Maven. 
 mvn install:install-file \
      -Dfile=/lib/ojdbc7.jar \
      -DgroupId=com.oracle \
      -DartifactId=ojdbc7 \
      -Dversion=12.1.0.1 \
      -Dpackaging=jar \
      -DgeneratePom=true

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has a Maven repository now. https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/get-oracle-jdbc-drivers-and-ucp-from-oracle-maven-repository-without-ides